# SQL Server CE 4.0, CodeFirst and GUID keys

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, code-first, guid

I'm using code-first to design my model and I chose GUID as a data type for my primary keys. My classes looks like this:

```
public class AccountMovementPlan
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated( System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )]
    public Guid AccountMovementPlanID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid UserAccountID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserAccountID")]
    public UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }     

// etc, etc, etc   
}
```

Next, I chose SQL Server CE 4.0 as my datastore, implemented configuration to use `SqlCEConnectionFactory` and use `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` as initialization method.

But, when I try to run my app, I'm greeted with an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException occurred in EntityFramework.dll

which is informing me, that

> The identity column must be either an integer or big integer data type and cannot be NULL.

My question is obvious: SQL Server CE with code-first doesn't support autogenerated GUIDs as PKs? Or, do I have an error somewhere?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not supported, you must use Guid.NewGuid() in your code to assign the value.